# Como convertir un array de string en un objeto

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, poo

Tengo varios array con los siguientes valores:

```
array1 = [2774.2374, 220.93711, 272.5424, 220.93711]
array2 = ['JABONERIA WILSON S.A', 'JABONERIA TOMAS.A', 'JABONERIA RAPIDEX.A', 'WILLEX S.A']
array3 = ['LAVAX VERDE 700 GRS. X CAJA X 12 UNDS.','LAVAX VERDE 900 GRS. X CAJA X 12 UNDS', 'LAVAX UVA 900 GRS. X CAJA X 12 UNDS.', 'LAVA LIQUIDO LIMON DOYPACK 1000 MLXUND']
```

Este es mi codigo donde obtengo los array antes mencionados:

```
  let array1 = [];
  let array2 = [];
  let array3 = [];

  let apifiltrada = {};

  const example = async () => {
    const api = await getData();
    const filtro = api.filter((el) => {
      const soles = el.soles;
      array1.push(soles);
      console.log(array1);
      const proveedor = el.proveedor;
      array2.push(proveedor);
      console.log(array2);
      const articulo = el.articulo;
      array3.push(articulo);
      console.log(array3);
    });
```

Como hago para crear un objeto con llave - valor que me quede de la siguiente manera :

Este es el objeto que necesito crear partir de los tres array antes mencionados por favor alguna idea.

```
[
{proveedor: 'JABONERIA WILSON S.A', producto: 'LAVAX VERDE 700 GRS. X CAJA X 12 UNDS.', soles: 2774.2374} 
{proveedor: 'JABONERIA TOMAS.A', producto: 'LAVAX VERDE 900 GRS. X CAJA X 12 UNDS', soles: 220.93711} 
{proveedor: 'JABONERIA RAPIDEX.A', producto: 'LAVAX UVA 900 GRS. X CAJA X 12 UNDS.', soles: 272.5424} 
{proveedor: 'WILLEX S.A', producto: 'LAVA LIQUIDO LIMON DOYPACK 1000 MLXUND', soles: 220.93711}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te puede dar algún acercamiento. También podría ser buena idea que comprobaras si los largos del array son iguales. Pero quizás esto no aplica en tu caso

```js
function GetArrObjetc(arrProveedor, arrProductos, arrSoles)
{
  let arr=[];
  for(let i in arrProveedor)
  {
    arr.push({
       proveedor: arrProveedor[i],
       producto: arrProductos[i],
       soles: arrSoles[i]
    });
  }
  return arr;
}

//prueba

let array1 = [2774.2374, 220.93711, 272.5424, 220.93711];
let array2 = ['JABONERIA WILSON S.A', 'JABONERIA TOMAS.A', 'JABONERIA RAPIDEX.A', 'WILLEX S.A'];
let array3 = ['LAVAX VERDE 700 GRS. X CAJA X 12 UNDS.','LAVAX VERDE 900 GRS. X CAJA X 12 UNDS', 'LAVAX UVA 900 GRS. X CAJA X 12 UNDS.', 'LAVA LIQUIDO LIMON DOYPACK 1000 MLXUND'];

console.log( GetArrObjetc(array2,array3,array1));
```

Comment: gracias si me funciono... y los array si tienen la misma longitud. Quedo perfecto